# Jersey 2.5: Replacement for JResponse?

Tags: java, rest, generics, jersey, jersey-2.0

In our Jersey 1.9 code, we have an annotation processor that runs at build time and produces documentation of our REST API. It does this by looking for @Paths and then looking at consumed form beans and JResponses. Since JResponse could take a generic like

```
public JResponse<MyRepresentation> findMyEntity(Long id)
```

The API documentation generator would read through methods like that, see the generic return type, and be able to reflectively generate a response definition based on `MyRepresentation`. In Jersey 2.x, I don't see anything like JResponse.

**Is there a comparable generic return/response type available for Jersey 2.x resource methods?**

Comment: Which documentation generator are you using? We use Jackson for Json serialisation, who doesn't need response objects to be wrapperd in a JResponse.

Comment: @bertvh The documentation generator was something we rolled in house, and could ditch for Swagger if we had to. Swagger always seemed like a lot more work to write and maintain documentation/annotations, whereas our home brewed tool worked from the Java code itself. We use Jackson for serialization, and it works as you've described. This only affects our documentation generation, not our server's ability to function.

Comment: We're working on a REST API documentation generator called [miredot](http://www.miredot.com). Should be easier to set up than Swagger and you can drop JResponse. We offer a very capable free version. Maybe something to try out? Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this even worth it?**

After not really getting a satisfactory answer, I've come to assume that either no one else was really using this feature, they weren't upset by losing it, or there are simply no satisfactory answers.

I really love the idea of a simple, compiler enforced, self-documenting API. It's always in sync because the compiler is going to complain if your returned type doesn't match, no in-code comments or external documentation structure required. To that end, I decided it was important enough that we could suffer a tiny amount of isolated "hackiness" in order to achieve API zen.

**Attempting a solution**

My first thought was to create a new JResponse via `public class JResponse<E> extends Response`, but it provides pretty much nil in the way of default functionality. So, deeper into Jersey land, I considered `public class JResponse<E> extends OutboundJaxrsResponse`. The trouble is still that the built-in ResponseBuilder is built to produce an OutboundJaxrsResponse, not my generecized JResponse. It seemed like there is supposed to be a way that you can inject your own ResponseBuilder, but I couldn't really figure out how to do that *while* adding generics (if anyone figures that out, it sounds like it might be a better solution than what I came up with).

The final solution I ended up with based on a number of factors is one abstract class extending `OutboundJaxrsResponse` and three response code specific classes, `Ok<E>`, `Created<E>`, and `NoContent` invoked as

```
// Some resource method
@Path("data/find")
public static Ok<MyDataRep> findData(@Valid MyDataRequestBean form) {
    // find entity etc
    MyDataRep somePojo = ...;
    return Ok.entity(somePojo);
}
```

It turns out that we use a remarkably small amount of the overall Response API in practice (only 200, 201, and 204 for success codes, no 300's, and everything 400+ via thrown exceptions) which meant redoing the whole builder pattern was unnecessary. In the end, it came out to

Ok: static empty, static entity(E entity)
Created: static uri, instance entity(E entity)
NoContent: static empty

A Created example would be `return Created.uri(someBuiltUri).entity(somePojo);`

**Downsides**

It wouldn't be fair to not discuss the downsides that exist, of which there are a few main ones.

First, since Response is still an ancestor (by requirement of Jersey), all of the Response static methods are visible and show up in IDE auto-completes. Since `Ok.ok()` doesn't match `Ok<E>`, it could be hard to realize what's going wrong until you're familiar with the dialect I've created here. This could be solved with a factory, though it would increase complexity.

Second, there's a place within Jersey's internals where it tries to ensure that correct type is being used when you're returning anything generic. There's a check to say "If this is an instanceof Response, don't do the check", but I believe it's bugged. The upshot is that Jersey mistakenly mangles your types and then blows up. In order to fix this, I had to do the following:

```
public static class CustomOutboundMessageContext extends OutboundMessageContext {
    @Override
    public void setEntityType(Type type) {}
}
```

This prevents the type information from being incorrectly rewritten.

Third, the comments in `Response` pretty specifically ask us not to do this:

```
/**
 * An application class should not extend this class directly. {@code Response} class is
 * reserved for an extension by a JAX-RS implementation providers. An application should use one
 * of the static methods to create a {@code Response} instance using a ResponseBuilder.
```

Fourth, I don't think it'd be fair to ignore the fragility of depending on internals of Jersey, though it can't be more fragile than depending on `JResponse` in the first place. Fortunately, we can always go back to `Response` if we had to; that option is still available.

**Conclusion**

The changes are really easy to use in our particular project and allows us to generate API definitions without having to maintain comments. Overall, I still feel it was worth the effort for us, but I can't recommend this as an ideal solution.